# Debugging plain JavaScript code without web project

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a JavaScript file that I'd like to edit and debug.

The code isn't DOM/browser/web specific.

Can I use VS Code to run and debug JavaScript without a web project like Node or ASP.NET? If so, how? Perhaps VS Code assumes it'll have a web server like Node to attach and debug

How should I modify my launch.json if necessary?

Loading a .js file and hitting F5 results in

> Connection Failed
>
> OpenDebug process has terminated unexpectedly

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same frustrating issue. The problem is node.exe is not in your PATH. You can check this by running cmd.exe, typing node and seeing if it runs or not. If it fails, this may help you:

Hit F5 in Code. It should create / open a **launch.json** file. In that file, change this line:

`"runtimeExecutable": null,`

to this:

`"runtimeExecutable": "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe",`

A more permanent solution would be to add node.exe to your PATH variable and reboot.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't because the debugger depends on the [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/) or [io.js](https://iojs.org/en/index.html) binaries installed and in your `PATH` variable. They host the code and provide introspection into it's states.

`launch.json` should be automatically populated, giving you a ready configuration for running and debugging.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can debug without no web project you just need to add a debug configuration and the chrome extension

find it here https://medium.com/young-coder/setting-up-javascript-debugging-in-visual-studio-code-6c5005529987